# Strange window popping on Gnome

Tags: gnome, screensaver, malware

A couple of days ago, when I came back to my computer after a couple of hours, the following window was on my desktop:

[image: 05:19:06 PM {Cancel} {OK}]

The title bar said "gnome-screensaver-dialog".  That's it.  I just clicked OK, and went on.
This has happened to me once before, but a long time ago.

Please note, I just have the plain blank screen as the screen saver.

Answer (score 7):

When you go away from the computer it lock.  On the unlock password screen there is a button so that someone can leave a message.  Is this a case of somehow a blank message got left?

Comment: I'll try it tonight and see what happens.  Thanks!

Comment: This is properly what happened, i just tried leving a blank message for my self and it showed up like that. This may be worth a feature request/bug report for the gnome team.

Comment: Spot on! Try locking your desktop - leaving a blank message and then logging back in.

Answer (score 2):

this is exactly the intended behavior.
It is there just in case someone needed you (or your computer) "while you were out". This way, they can leave you a message, without breaching into your computer for that.
Say you went to the restroom, and a co-worker wanted to have you look-up something for them, this way, they can just leave you a message and let you know without having to track you down or leave it on a post-it (which may not be available).
The only problem here is maybe we should have the devs add a title bar or other such information to the message that will let the user know it is a "while you were out" message, as opposed to just "something from gnome-screensaver".